# Oracle Timestamp index very slow

Tags: sql, oracle, date, count, timestamp

I've got this table:

```
CREATE TABLE "TEST"."TEST_REQUESTS"
  (
    "REQUEST_ID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "RECEPTION_TIME" TIMESTAMP (6) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "OPERATION" VARCHAR2(25 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "XML_HEADER_IN" CLOB,
    "XML_BODY_IN" CLOB NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "STATUS_ID" NUMBER(*,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "CUSTOMER"  VARCHAR2(25 BYTE)
  )
```

and it has 2 indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX "TEST"."TEST_REQUESTS_STATUS_IDX" ON "TEST"."TEST_REQUESTS"
    (
      "STATUS_ID" DESC
    )
CREATE INDEX "TEST"."TEST_REQUESTS_TIME_IDX" ON "TEST"."TEST_REQUESTS"
    (
      "RECEPTION_TIME"
    )
```

I also have a procedure more or less like this:

```
PROCEDURE TEST_LoadHistoryRequestRange (diasMantenidosIN IN number, [...] numRequestOut OUT number [...]) IS

tsStartLimit TIMESTAMP;

BEGIN

tsStartLimit := sysdate - diasMantenidosIN;

SELECT count(REQUEST_ID) into numRequestOut FROM TEST_REQUESTS WHERE STATUS_ID=0 and RECEPTION_TIME<tsStartLimit;

[...]

END;
```

Now the table has grown up to near 15 million registers... but, is it logical to take near 10 minutes long to make that simple `COUNT`? What can be wrong with this?

Thank you very much!!

EDIT: This is the explain plan for the select count:

```
Plan hash value: 378939817

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                    | Name                      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |                           |     1 |    14 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE              |                           |     1 |    14 |            |          |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TEST_REQUESTS             |  1125 | 15750 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  3 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN          | TEST_REQUESTS_STATUS_IDX  |     1 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What is the distribution of the data, particularly for `status_id` but also for the timestamps? How selective would using either index (or Gordon's new one) be? Can you add the explain plan for the current query? Whatever access path it's choosing, 10 minutes to count a subset of 15 million rows still sounds high.

Comment: @AlexPoole i just pasted the explain plan. What do you mean by the "distribution of the data"? i don't really know how to answer to your questions, i'm still newbie at oracle.

Answer (score 2):

It can take a long time.  The best index for your query is a composite index:

```
CREATE INDEX "TEST"."TEST_STATUS_REQUESTS_TIME_IDX" ON "TEST"."TEST_REQUESTS"
    (
      STATUS,
      "RECEPTION_TIME",
      REQUEST_ID
    );
```

Note that the order of the columns in the index makes a difference.

Comment: i just created that index, but its still using TEST_REQUESTS_STATUS_IDX (i've used "explain plan"). should i delete the old indexes?

Comment: @lozan . . . Oracle should be smart enough to use this index if appropriate . . . and if the statistics are up-to-date.  You can probably force this index if you delete other (or if you use a hint in the query).

Comment: i just updated my statistics:
EXEC dbms_stats.gather_schema_stats('TEST', cascade=>TRUE);
But it's still using the other index...

Comment: This is the explain plan that i used with the hint:

explain plan for SELECT /*+ INDEX(TEST_REQUESTS TEST_STATUS_REQUESTS_TIME_IDX) */ count(REQUEST_ID) FROM TEST_REQUESTS WHERE STATUS_ID=0 and RECEPTION_TIME<systimestamp;